# ¿Cómo agregar un Template personalizado php en wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Buenos días, necesito agregar a mi tema "Galio theme" una pagina personalizada que creé en php, investigando en Internet si uso el siguiente código:

```
 <?php  
/* 
Template Name: Mi plantilla personalizada 
*/  
?>
```

Debería aparecerme en la sección de plantillas personalizadas pero no me muestra nada. ¿Será que me faltó algo?
Esas plantillas que muestro en la imagen ya venían con el tema, he copiado y pegado esas mismas plantillas pero no pasa nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aprueba una de las respuestas como respuesta de la pregunta para que el resto de gente sepa cual es la que funcionó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema puede venir porque lo estas intentado hacer desde el propio tema padre.

¿Has probado a crear tu propio tema hijo? Es la mejor manera de crear funcionalidades añadidas a tu actual tema, y ademas de eso es la manera correcta de desarrollar este tipo de cosas.

Aquí te dejo una [guía del codex de Wordpress de como crear tu tema hijo](https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Temas_hijos):

Como veras es muy sencillo y te permite hacer cambios en tu tema pudiendo actualizar el tema principal sin problema.

Comment: gracias me funciono de esta manera ;) claro investigando un poco en internet para la creacion del tema hijo pero funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Hola la sintaxis está correcta, puede que no te aparezca por la forma como guardaste el archivo, intenta guardar el archivo "page-(nombre-del-archivo).php" y revisa nuevamente la sección de plantillas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, aun nada no me salen :S estuve leyendo y según dicen aveces desactivan la funcionalidad de agregar mas templates personalizados los creadores del theme pero no se en que parte encontrar eso para desactivarlo.